# How to create a trunk after merge from multiple developer branches in SVN (Tortoise SVN)

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

My team is new to SVN, and I think we made a mistake of each developer creating their own branch and started adding code to their own branches.  Now, I need to merge all the branches into a trunk.  is there a safe way to do this?  I've been working on it, but I keep getting the "tree conflict" error when there's a file in a branch, that is not in the trunk.  Most of the files would be added, except for a few that would generate the error.

The trunk is initially empty, and I'm trying to merge one branch at a time.

We're using Tortoise SVN 1.7.9.

this is our current structure.

```
projectFoo

    - branches
        - dev1
            - proj1

        - dev2
            - proj1

        - dev3
            etc...

    - trunk
        - <empty>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have a fun time since everyone is working in their own branch, and the branches have nothing to do with each other. This isn't a *merge* in the programming sense. A true merge means that you split *Branch "A"* from *Branch "B"*, so the two branches have a common ancestor revision, and you're now merging from "A" to "B" or "B" to "A".

There is no easy way to do what you need to do. If you are lucky, all of the developers are working on separate code, so merging simply means merging the branches together, and you'll have no real conflicts. If developers are working on the same file, but in different branches, you're in trouble.

You will need to use the `--ignore-ancestors` parameter when merging since there is no ancestor. That's the only thing I can say. However, once you get over this pain, you can resolve to use a more standard way of handling branching and merging. There are two paradigms
that are actually good to use. (There are several others, but they're basically toxic):

- **Unstable Trunk**: My personal favorite. Everyone works off of trunk. It's the way God designed Subversion to work. Branching is only done *when necessary*. The definition of *when necessary* is a bit nebulous. Basically, you branch when you need to because you don't want developers idle.
- **Stream Development**: In Stream Development, you have an *integration stream* (usually *trunk*) and developers create _development streams (aka branches) to do their work. A development stream might be a developer's personal workspace, an Agile task, a Jira issue, a feature. You basically create a branch off of trunk, do the work, *rebase* (aka merge from trunk to the development <strike>branch</strike> *stream*), and _deliver (aka merging from the development stream back to trunk).

As you can see, in the **Unstable trunk**, everything is very simple because there is very little branching going on. And since everyone works off of trunk, they communicate a bit better with everyone, and they take smaller development bites. It works great when combined with *Continuous Integration*.

When do you branch in the Unstable Trunk? Usually when you start finishing up one revision, and developers start working on the current revision and then next. Let's say everyone is working on release 1.2. Everyone works on the trunk. When you get to the point where some of the developers finish work on 1.2 and want to work on release 1.3, and there is still some cleanup work on release 1.2 to do, you branch a 1.2 release branch off of trunk.

Developers working on release 1.3 continue working on trunk. Developers firming up release 1.2 work on the 1.2 branch. When 1.2 i ready to be released, the 1.2 release is done off the 1.2 branch and tagged on the 1.2 branch. If a patch/hotfix release 1.2.1 is needed, it's also done on the 1.2 branch.

If an issue is found on the 1.2 branch and it also is an issue on the 1.3 release on trunk, you can easily merge that particular change on 1.2 back to trunk since the 1.2 branch came from trunk.

The Stream Development is favored by the Agile crowd because it allows you to pick and chose what to include in the *integration branch* (aka trunk). Many times, software isn't delivered into trunk until the sprint is almost complete. People who like this method like it because it offers *flexibility*, but I don't like it because continuous integration doesn't work too well with this method. Plus, you usually don't have a decent build until a few days before a release.